# SpeedDialAction with react-router-dom Link

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My `SpeedDialAction` looks like this:

```
<SpeedDialAction key="Add" icon={<AddIcon />} tooltipTitle="Add" />
```

I want to navigate to /add when the action is clicked. Is there a way to do this without using `onClick` and using the push `/add` to the history manually?

For example a button allows something like this:

```html
<Button
  component={Link}
  to={`ticket/${ticket.id}`}
  variant="contained"
  color="primary"
>
  Details
</Button>
```

Comment: Why you need the `SpeedDialAction`? You can use `<Fab />` with `position: absolute`, similar to: https://material-ui.com/components/floating-action-button/#animation (not the animation part but the position)

Comment: But then I can only have one action right? With SpeedDial I have the option add multiple actions.

Comment: O, you want that the speed dial **menu** will lead to different pages, I thought you're talking about the button itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap the icon with `<Link />`.

Based on [their](https://material-ui.com/components/speed-dial/#simple-speed-dial) example, you can wrap it like this:

```js
const withLink = (to, children) => <Link to={to}>{children}</Link>;

const actions = [
  { icon: withLink("/about", <LiveHelpIcon />), name: "About" },
  { icon: withLink("/users", <GroupIcon />), name: "Users" }
];
```

(You can obviously also do it in the "normal" way)

```js
{ icon: <Link to="/about"><LiveHelpIcon /></Link>), name: "About" },
```

Then, wrap the `<SpeedDial />` with `<Router>` and add `<Switch>` just after it, like this:

```js
<Router>
  <SpeedDial
    ariaLabel="SpeedDial example"
    className={classes.speedDial}
    icon={<SpeedDialIcon />}
    onClose={handleClose}
    onOpen={handleOpen}
    open={open}
  >
    {actions.map(action => (
      <SpeedDialAction
        key={action.name}
        icon={action.icon}
        tooltipTitle={action.name}
        onClick={handleClose}
      />
    ))}
  </SpeedDial>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/about">
      <div>About</div>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/users">
      <div>Users</div>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/">
      <div>Home</div>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-speeddial-react-router-dom-bmmwi

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did not realize icon could be any ReactNode. Does Link just render the children component and adds a href to It?

Comment: Sure :) Link is similar to `a` tag in html. Instead of `href` it has `to` and like `a` it can has children.

Comment: This works, but it messes up the alignment (icons become higher than center). Any guesses on why or how to prevent that?

Comment: @m4cbeth the icon element (`svg`) should have `display: block`. I've updated the demo. (Pay attention to the highlighted lines): https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-speeddial-react-router-dom-bmmwi?file=/demo.js:1004-1048

Comment: @MoshFeu Thank you, that's a great solution. I used a bit of a different fix, applied `display: flex` to the `<Link>` component. Either way, perfect end result!